# Setting Javascript date object to midnight without being based on user computer date

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I need to set a date and time to 12 midnight regardless of the user's computer date. I am creating an international meeting planner to offset time zones to get the meeting.

I have it working but I need to code now the differences in time zones. If I use new Date, it gives me the time based on the user's computer. For example, mine is Eastern US. If I try to do the time zone shift on November 6, 2011, Javascript/computer will calculate MY time zone shift at 2am. I do not want this.

My real goal is to set it to 12 midnight in the timezone that is where the meeting will be hosted from (let's say Afghanistan) and then calculate from there.

So:

1. How do I set 12 midnight without being being the user's computer time?
2. Can I set 12 midnight to a specific time zone, without being dependent on user's computer time?

I have to do this with Javascript as there is no server code involved.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to check out http://www.datejs.com/ I'm not sure if it will solve you specific issue but it has a wealth of features on top of the normal date variable.

Comment: Accept some answers for previous questions and you'll be more likely to get some help. 6 questions and not one accepted answer?

Comment: How on earth are you going to host an online meeting with no server code?

Comment: First off, I'm not sure how to do do an accepted answer. It doesn't really tell you how.

Comment: datejs is buggy and it doesn't have what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user581733 Click the "checkmark" by the one answer per question that best answers your question. (It's OK to not accept an answer if you have not yet gotten a proper answer.)

Comment: To accept an answer, go to the answer you like, and on the left side they'll be an up arrow (to vote up the post), the current votes, a down arrow and below it a checkmark.  Click on the checkmark to accept (it will becomes solid green).  You should also up-vote any answers that were helpful.

Comment: @drjimbob Note that this user does not yet have sufficient reputation to upvote/downvote answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this I would guess: `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))`

[w3schools Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp)

Comment: As for not having server code, we don't need it. Everything is done in HTML, Javascript.

Comment: What do you mean? The method is supported: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Comment: It doesn't do what I want it to do. If I set it to UTC, then the browser will always add in the timezone difference for where I'm at, not the actual UTC time. Thus, I never get 12 midnight utc.

Comment: Plus I don't want the milliseconds. I need to set the UTC time to 12 midnight and work on that figure. I don't think it can be done as it's something with the browser. It will always give back the local time (i.e., UTC minus the timezone difference from the local computer).

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but I would accept answers if it were more intuitive how to do it. It's not really not. I maybe missing something. Plus, I don't et email alerts if anyone answered the question even though I specify it. I have to constantly refresh the page.

Comment: @Phrogz: I actually didn't know that. Lol.

Comment: I need to know how to accept this answer :-) I even looked at the FAQ here and it didn't tell me.

Comment: There is a grey checkmark to the left of the answer. Click it. It will turn green.

Comment: I'm under IE8 and there's no checkmark at all by the answer. I would send a screenshot if needed.

Comment: Ooops, I found it when I redrew the screen. I'll go back to my other questions :-)

Comment: It's actually not answered because time in javascript will always be dependant on the user clock. There's no way around it. If I try to run the meeting planner on 3/13/2011, it will repeat 1am twice because of the time shift on the East Coast (where I am located), even though I'm setting the clock to UTC and placing in times for Kabul and London. If I can't use server code on my side, is there an api or server I can ping (like google) for the time?

Answer (score 0):

To create midnight in GMT:

```
// Note: months are 0-based, so 7 == august
var midnight = new Date( Date.UTC(2011,7,15) );
// Sun Aug 14 2011 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

To create midnight in another time zone:

```
var mdt = -6; // Mountain Daylight Time
var midnightMDT = new Date( Date.UTC(2011,7,15,-mdt) );
//-> Mon Aug 15 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Date objects are expressed in the local time zone of the user, but they are still representative of midnight in another time zone.

If you want to express a date in another time zone, you'll need to offset the date to that timezone (`setUTCHours()`) and then use the various getUTC* methods (e.g. `getUTCHours()`) to construct your own string.

Comment: @user581733 You're welcome. If you find that this has helped you, you might show your appreciation by upvotes and/or clicking the checkmark of 'acceptance'.